# Python AST NodeTransformer: Return multiple nodes

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

Is there an easy way to return multiple nodes to replace a single node when using the ast.NodeTransformer? For example, say I want to rewrite all expressions of the form

`f(g())` to `_x1 = g(); g(_x1)`

It would be quite easy to do this if `visit_Expr` could return multiple, rather than a single node. I couldn't seem to get that to work though, so I assume this is *not* the way to do this. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

`[Update]`
As an update, I have a working version of this that accumulates the new and old nodes in a list, and assigns them to the body of the enclosing scope node (e.g. `For`, `While`, `Module` node etc). This is definitely a hacky way of doing it, and suspect there is a better way out there. I'll keep this around in case someone knows of that way.

`[final update]` looking at the docs for `NodeTransformer` it's actually entirely possible to return a list of nodes, if the node is part of a collection of statements.

Comment: Please include how you didn't get returning multiple nodes to work; include your attempts so I can help you with *that*. Returning multiple nodes as a list is *explicitly supported*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For *statement* nodes, you are allowed to return a list of new nodes. This lets you replace a single statement with multiple. Quoting the documentation:

> For nodes that were part of a collection of statements (that applies to all statement nodes), the visitor may also return a list of nodes rather than just a single node.

For your expression, there is a single top-level `Expr()` expression statement node:

```
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse('f(g())'))
"Module(body=[Expr(value=Call(func=Name(id='f', ctx=Load()), args=[Call(func=Name(id='g', ctx=Load()), args=[], keywords=[])], keywords=[]))])"
>>> import ast
>>> ast.dump(ast.parse('f(g())'))
"Module(body=[Expr(value=Call(func=Name(id='f', ctx=Load()), args=[Call(func=Name(id='g', ctx=Load()), args=[], keywords=[])], keywords=[]))])"
```

So all you have to do is supply a `visit_Expr` handler that returns a list of 2 statement nodes; the first an assignment (`Assign()` statement node) of a call to `g()`, the second of a call to `f` passing in the new variable name (another `Expr()` statement node).

I'd keep state in the transformer subclass that sets flags when you enter and leave an expression statement context, and keeps track of the stack of calls under that context. When you then return to `visit_Expr`, you return your new setup:

```
self._expr_statement = False

def visit_Expr(node):
    self._expr_statement = True
    self.generic_visit(node)
    self._expr_statement = False

    if <specific state on self matches expectations>:
        tempvar = <generated_new_name>
        return [
            Assign([Name(tempvar, Store())], <inner_call>),
            Expr(Call(
                <outer_function_name_expr>,
                args=[Name(tempvar, Load())],
                keyword=[]))
        ]
    else:
        # no replacement takes place
        return node
```

The `NodeTransformer then uses that list of elements to replace the previous`Expr()` node.

Note that you have to call `self.generic_visit(node)` still to ensure that the nested nodes are still handled; further `visit_*` methods will then be called for those nested nodes. This then makes it so that inside a `visit_Call` method you could check the `self._expr_statement` flag and then test if there is a nested call, then store enough context on `self` for the `visit_Expr()` method to return.

Comment: Thanks. This is the solution I converged on :) Was about to post, but since you clearly answered with detail, I'm accepting yours. I missed the original point in the docs about being able to return multiple nodes for top-level `Expr`. Should have inspected the source code. Thanks again! * Didn't mean that to come across as "I had already solved", but rather wanted to thank since this validates what I thought made sense, which is super useful

Comment: One comment, I think you'd want to call `generic_visit` rather than `visit` within `visit_Expr`, since otherwise it just goes into infinite recursion. `generic_visit` will dispatch the appropriate `visit_*` for children nodes, since the right method is resolved in `super().visit`